# Check if the certificate is Root CA, issuing CA, service server of client

Tags: openssl

Trying to automate a identifying execution to check if the certificate is Root CA, issuing CA, service server of client via openssl command in a script batch. How do we do that? And how do we do that in command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject and issuer can gives us an idea.

CA
$ openssl x509 -subject -issuer -noout -in RCA.Zone_A.crt

```
subject=CN = www.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, emailAddress = RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048@RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, O = RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048, L = CA, C = US

issuer=CN = www.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, emailAddress = RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048@RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, O = RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048, L = CA, C = US
```

Intermediate CA
$ openssl x509 -subject -issuer -noout -in ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.crt

```
subject=CN = www.ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, emailAddress = ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048@ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, O = ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048, L = CA, C = US

issuer=CN = www.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, emailAddress = RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048@RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, O = RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048, L = CA, C = US
```

relying service
$ openssl x509 -subject -issuer -noout -in service_00.ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.crt

```
subject=CN = www.service_00.ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, emailAddress = service_00.ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048@service_00.ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, O = service_00.ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048, L = CA, C = US

issuer=CN = www.ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, emailAddress = ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048@ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048.com, O = ICA_00.RCA.Zone_A.rsa2048, L = CA, C = US
```